# Use magit to find out who wrote the line at point and when

Tags: magit

Someone showed me how to do this with "ruby mine" but I don't use ruby mine so hoping emacs / magit can do this.

A file in a git repository is opened up in emacs. Point is at line 23, and you want to quickly find out some "extra info" about this line, such as, who authored this line of code, and when was it last touched upon by someone.

Comment: Have you tried `magit-blame`?

Comment: that works! looks like that's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The activity you are describing is commonly called "blaming". Magit's manual contains [a section about blaming](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Blaming.html).

The easiest way to show such information is to type <kbd>C-c M-g b</kbd> in a file-visiting buffer, but there are alternative approaches as described in the manual.